# Not able to install App in emulator - Not enough space

Tags: android, android-source, qemu

I tried to install an app and got an exception
 `" your device doesn't have enough space to install the app."`

I tried increasing the `SYSTEM_PARTITION_SIZE` in `BoardConfig.mk`  by 1GB .Took a new build and I can see that the `system-qemu.img` size increased by 1GB.

Still I am getting space issues when I try to install new app. 
Could someone provide me some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your emulator phone. If possible, delete it and reinstall the OS image.
If the issue still persists, consider reviewing your apps size.

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing the app after flash, it goes in /data/data , which is usually in userdata.img ( in boards I've used, not sure about emulator ).

Increasing system.img size is only relevant for system apps that come pre-installed in that partition

Comment: I increased both system_partition_size and  userdata_partition_size in BoardConfig..It didn't fix however